# Why I cannot parse "+1" to int?

Tags: java

I am trying to parse `+1` value to an `int` value. In my code `+1` is a `String` and i am trying to convert it to `Integer` using `Integer.parseInt`,

```
String num = "+1";
int convertedNum = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

but I am getting error, why Java is not treating `+1` as an integer value ?

Comment: that is not a duplicate, the answer in the suggested question is old (2010) and it didn't say anything about this being fixed in JDK1.7, so these question doesn't seem related at all.

Comment: @bhuvesh it'd be fine to add an answer to the other question, noting that java's behavior has changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

because you must be using older version of JDK (JDK < 7). Before *Java 7*, 
`+1` wasn't considered as a valid integer.

> Prior to `JDK 1.7`, what was the result of the following code segment?
>
> `double x = Double.parseDouble("+1.0");`
>
> `int n = Integer.parseInt("+1");`
>
> Pat yourself on the back if you knew the
>   answer: `+1.0` has always been a valid floating-point number, but
>   until Java 7, `+1` was not a valid integer. This has now been fixed
>   for all the various methods that construct `int`, `long`, `short`, `byte`,
>   and `BigInteger` values from strings. There are more of them than you
>   may think. In addition to parse (Int|Long|Short|Byte), there are
>   decode methods that work with hexadecimal and octal inputs, and
>   `valueOf` methods that yield wrapper objects. The `BigInteger(String)`
>   constructor is also updated.

Comment: So -1 was valid and +1 wasn't?

Comment: It's Java, they still don't believe in unsigned numbers. Probably why it can't handle signs properly.

Comment: thank you , i am so dumb to not realize that.